# Grid Problem - How to get from Point A to B while avoiding segment CD

Tags: combinatorics

Very curious on how to solve this problem. Let's say I'm given a grid problem but we want to avoid segment BC and get to point D from point A with the condition that you can only go right and up. How would we go about solving this?
[Hand drawn pic of a graph with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQDlJ.png)

Comment: Is this one of those questions where you can only go up or to the right?  That's not explicitly stated in your question, unless it's implicit in the definition of "grid problem."

Comment: @RobertShore Ah yes, missed it. Added it

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- How many total ways from $A$ to $D$?
- How many ways from $A$ to $D$ using $BC$?

  - How many ways from $A$ to $B$?
  - How many ways from $C$ to $D$?
- How many ways from $A$ to $D$ *not* using $BC$?